# how to add new pages using WP core function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

how can I add a page using core functions of wordpress.I can find function for Post etc as well but couldn't find any for Pages.Any one who can help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same function to add posts or pages, just add the `post_type` parameter like this :

```
$args = array( 'post_type'  => 'page',
               'post_content' => 'You content...',
               'post_parent' => $parent_id; // ID of the page this one should be a child of
... // etc.
...
               'post_title' => 'Title for your page');

wp_insert_post ($args);
```

Comment: P.S.: don't forget to sanitize content especially if there is user input